# Retrieve array submission script

Tags: slurm

I am looking for an equivalent of

```
sacct -j <jobid> -B
```

but for arrays, to find the script used to submit the array of jobs.
Unfortunately, using the command above to find the submission script for any job of the array yields "NONE".

After some searching, I have found out this might be possible with the ElasticSearch plugin or sarchive. However, I can't find info on whether this is possible with the standard option for job accounting (\i.e. slurmdbd).

I am suspecting the submission script is not part of the recorded info on the database, but I haven't been able to confirm it.

Comment: Any luck with scontrol show <jobid>?

Comment: It doesn't work with completed jobs.

Comment: Does it `sacct -j <jobid> -B` work for non-array jobs?

Comment: It does, when slurm configuration is setup for archiving that info, which I think it is the case by default.